# Embedding Powershell CTP 2 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have an application that has Powershell 1 embedded into it, but we need to be able to use Powershell STAThreaded which is available in Powershell 2 CTP. Currently, System.Management.Automation is at 1.0.0.0. Does anyone know how to get Visual Studio to use the newer dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll look into it, but you realize that there is absolutely no guarantee that anything in the CTP will stay the way that it is right now? Most likely it will, but I wouldn't develop against it right now.

EDIT: As a matter of fact this is a quote from the CTP download page:

> **This software is a pre-release version. It will not work the way a final version of the software does. Features will change before final release.**

Comment: Yeah, I know but I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can yet, to use powershell V1.0 you needed to download "Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5" to get the dll file that you referenced.  You would now need to find a SDK that has the dll for the CPT file(Maybe the CPT includes the dll, I think it's called System.Management.Automation.dll in the V1.0 version).

Good Luck